# In a LongListSelector how can I get data from multiple parts of a LongListSelectorItem

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

So, I have a `LongListSelector` with a `CheckBox` and it is bound to a `List<People>` object

```
<phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="Auto">
            <CheckBox Tap="CheckedBox"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"/>
            <TextBlock Text=" "/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
```

I have the following event handler

```
private void CheckedBox(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((bool)(((CheckBox)sender).IsChecked))
    {   
        (Person)LongList1.SelectedItem).Attend[(App.Current as App).eventCount] = 'Y';
    }
}
```

This is inconsistent. How can I fix this so I can use the `CheckBox` value to change the object the `LongListSelectorItem` links to?

Answer (score 0):

You bind it to a value (bool perhaps) on your People-object and set the Mode=TwoWay.

```
Checked="{Binding=IsMale, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```